# Modified Equation for Euler Scheme

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the ODE
$$\dot{u} = f(u)$$
with $f$ globally Lipschitz so a solution exists and is unique. I can use an explicit Euler scheme to solve this via the iterates
$$u_{n+1} = u_n + hf(u_n)$$
and this numerical scheme will be consistent with my ODE to order $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$. If I instead considered the ODE
$$\sum_{k=1}^p \frac{h^{k-1}}{k!} \frac{d^k u}{dt^k} = f(u) $$
then the same numerical scheme will be consistent with this ODE to order $\mathcal{O}(h^{p+1})$; this is easily verifiable via Taylor expansion.
My question is what happens when we let $p \rightarrow \infty$? In particular, if I define the sequence of linear operators $T_p : C^\infty ([0,\infty); \mathbb{R}^d) \rightarrow C^\infty ([0,\infty); \mathbb{R}^d)$ via
$$T_p u = \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{h^{k-1}}{k!} \frac{d^k u}{dt^k}$$
then is there a limiting operator $T$ such that $T_p \rightarrow T$ as $p \rightarrow \infty$. If there is, what can I say about it? Does it have a closed form? Intuitively, one would think that this does convernge because if we just look at the coefficients 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{h^{k-1}}{k!} = \frac{e^h - 1}{h}$$ 
but I'm not sure how to connect this. I can't seem to find much literature for modified equations for ODE(s), so any reference would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why would the expression in terms of a sum be consistent to order $O(h^{p+1})$?

Comment: Let $u$ denote the solution to the summed ODE and define $u_n = u(nh)$ then Taylor expanding $u_{n+1} = u_n + \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{h^k}{k!}u^{(k)}_n + \mathcal{O}(h^{p+1})$ hence $u_{n+1}-u_n = hf(u_n) + \mathcal{O}(h^{p+1})$ showing consistency.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want to express these k-th order derivatives in terms of $f$? Basically, any text book on numerical solution of ODE's should treat things like Runge-Kutta methods and the like. Those methods are all basically variants of your idea.

Comment: I recommend reading about the method of differential approximation (developed by Shokin and his coauthors). There, the modified equations (for one order higher in your expansion, not the limit w.r.t to $p$) are considered and properties of numerical schemes are analyzed through the connections between the equation to be solved and the equation which is solved by the difference scheme.